# Find how much xtreme distance two people walk together

Tags: c++, arrays

Amir and Bond are walking on a street. Initially, both are at the position X=0 and they start walking in the direction of increasing X. After N seconds, they stop. Let's denote Amir's speed and Bond's speed during the i-th of these seconds by Ai and Bi respectively.

Sometimes, Aman and Bond walk together, i.e. with the same speed side by side. Let's define the xtreme distance as the total distance they walk this way. Find this xtreme distance.

Input
The first line of the input contains a single integer T denoting the number of test cases. The description of T test cases follows.
The first line of each test case contains a single integer N.
The second line contains N space-separated integers A1,A2,…,AN.
The third line contains N space-separated integers B1,B2,…,BN.
Output
For each test case, print a single line containing one integer ― the total weird distance. It can be proved that this distance is an integer.

**Constraints**

```
1≤T≤20
1≤N≤10e5
1≤Ai≤10e5 for each valid i
1≤Bi≤10e5 for each valid i
the sum of N over all test cases does not exceed 10e6
```

**Code**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int T;
    cin >> T;
    while(T--)
    {
        long long int N;
        long long int i, w = 0;
        cin >> N;
        int * A = new int [N+1];
        int * X = new int [N+1];
        int * B = new int [N+1];
        int * Y = new int [N+1];

        Y[0] = 0;
        X[0] = 0;

        for(i=1;i<=N;i++)
        {
            cin >> A[i];
            X[i] = X[i-1] + A[i];
        }   

        for(i=1;i<=N;i++)
        {
            cin >> B[i];
            Y[i] = Y[i-1] + B[i]; 
        }

        for(i=1;i<=N;i++)
        {
            if((X[i]-X[i-1]) == (Y[i]-Y[i-1]))
                w += (Y[i] - Y[i-1]);
        }      

        cout << w << endl;

        delete [] A;
        delete [] B;     
        delete [] X;
        delete [] Y;   
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**Example Input**

```
3
4
1 3 3 4
1 2 4 4
2
2 3
3 2
2
3 3
3 3
```

**Example Output**

```
5
0
6
```

**Error**

I am not able to figure out the error (may be there is error in constraints)

Comment: What input and expected output does your code fail on? And what output do you get?

Comment: @cigien It doesn't fail for the given inputs but answer is not accepted by the website

Comment: Then it will be very hard for us to help you. You need to show a test case where your code fails.

Comment: Am i correct in terms of constraints usually i get stuck in defining large arrays

Comment: I would recommend avoiding arrays entirely, and using `std::vector` and `std::string` instead.